# Programmatically creating a toolbar in WPF

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to create a simple toolbar in WPF, but the toolbar shows up with no corresponding buttons on it, just a very thin blank white strip. Any idea what I'm doing wrong, or what the recommended procedure is? Relevant code fragments so far:

```
        var tb = new ToolBar();

        var b = new Button();
        b.Command = comback;
        Image myImage = new Image();
        myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("back.png", UriKind.Relative));
        b.Content = myImage;
        tb.Items.Add(b);

        var p = new DockPanel();
        //DockPanel.SetDock(mainmenu, Dock.Top);
        DockPanel.SetDock(tb, Dock.Top);
        DockPanel.SetDock(sb, Dock.Bottom);
        //p.Children.Add(mainmenu);
        p.Children.Add(tb);
        p.Children.Add(sb);
        Content = p;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a third child-element for the Dockpanel p, the 'sb' element will fill everything except for the area of tb. The ToolBar will autoSize (its Height) according to its contents.

I suggest adding a simple text button first, to check the overall layout:

```
var b2 = new Button();   
b2.Content = "B2";
tb.Items.Add(b2);
```

And then investigate what is wrong with the "back.png" image.

Comment: Thanks, that approach worked! Turned out for some reason the relative Uri path doesn't work, so the image has to be loaded with myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/back.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));